# scrapy splash gets part of data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I ´m getting this error when I run my scraper :

```
2022-09-19 23:17:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.justforsport.com.ar/top-mujer-reebok-ts-ubf-seamless-rojo/p> (referer: https://www.justforsport.com.ar/mujer?page=7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\just_for_sport\just_for_sport\spiders\jfs_mujer.py", line 41, in parse_article_detail
    precio0=response.css('span.vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyContainer.vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyContainer--product')[0]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Personal\DABRA\Scraper_jfs\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 70, in __getitem__
    o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I try to understand what does it mean, but I can´t find the problem. The link works fine...but data is not collected...

My script looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from concurrent.futures import process
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime
import os

if os.path.exists('jfs_mujer.csv'):
    os.remove('jfs_mujer.csv')
    print("The file has been deleted successfully")
else:
    print("The file does not exist!")

class JfsSpider_mujer(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jfs_mujer'
    start_urls = ["https://www.justforsport.com.ar/mujer?page=1"]            

    def parse(self,response):
       # total_products=int(int(response.css('div.vtex-search-result-3-x-totalProducts--layout.pv5.ph9.bn-ns.bt-s.b--muted-5.tc-s.tl.t-action--small span::text').get())/32) + 2
        for count in range(1, 40):
            yield SplashRequest(url=f'https://www.justforsport.com.ar/mujer?page={count}',
                          callback=self.parse_links, meta= {'splash': {'endpoint': 'execute', 'args': {'wait': 0.5}}})

   #Extrae links de cada pagina de la seccion
    def parse_links(self,response):
        links=response.css('a.vtex-product-summary-2-x-clearLink.vtex-product-summary-2-x-clearLink--shelf-product.h-100.flex.flex-column::attr(href)').getall()  
        for link in links:
            yield SplashRequest(response.urljoin('https://www.justforsport.com.ar' + link), self.parse_article_detail ,meta= {'splash': {'endpoint': 'execute', 'args': {'wait': 0.5}}})
        
      
    def parse_article_detail(self, response):
        precio0=response.css('span.vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyContainer.vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyContainer--product')[0]
        yield {
            'Casa':'Just_For_Sports',
            'Sku' :response.css('span.vtex-product-identifier-0-x-product-identifier__value::text').get(),
            'Name':response.css('span.vtex-store-components-3-x-productBrand::text').get() ,
            'precio':''.join(precio0.css('span.vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyInteger.vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyInteger--product::text').getall()),
            'Link':response.url,
            'Date':datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                 }

process= CrawlerProcess(
    settings = { 
        'FEED_URI':'jfs_mujer.csv' ,
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING':'utf-8',
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 3,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 3,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':24,
        #'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY' : 12,
        'USER_AGENT' : 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
        } )        
            
process.crawl(JfsSpider_mujer)
process.start()
```

What's wrong wit the script? or it's something about settings? . I think it has something to do with the way I join the prices, but from 770 products, it works fine for almost 660...I don´t understand... thanks for touyr help!

Comment: What it means is that the CSS selector you specified does not exist.  You should probably print your HTML and triple-check that the CSS selector is valid.

Comment: error shows line `precio0=response.css(...)[0]` and probably this `[0]` makes problem because probably `css()` gives empty list. You could use `print()` to see what you really have in HTML because it may send you different data - ie. warning for bots/hackers/spamers or Captcha to check if you are human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message means that your CSS selector doesn't find anything.
You can try above XPath to get the price:

```
price = response.xpath('//meta[@property="product:price:amount"]/@content').get()
```